# В скрипте, вызванном через exec() curl_init выдаёт ошибку

Tags: php, curl, exec

Есть код:

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($curl, $this->getCurlOptions($params));
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Отрабатывает он нормально, но когда я этот же скрипт вызываю через `exec()`, то скрипт отрабатывает нормально до вызова `curl_init`, а затем кидает ошибку:

```
Call to undefined function curl_init()
```

Не могу понять чем это вызвано.

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan  Если я запускаю скрипт посредством `exec`, то он мне в логи прописывает данную ошибку. Если же я запускаю скрипт из браузера, то всё нормально.

`exec("php -q testHandler.php $path $type $typeUpdate $token $endPoint > script.log &");`

Comment: `extension=curl`в `php.ini` (который использует php после exec) есть? Просто для  для php-cli может использоваться другой php.ini

Comment: @chernomyrdin, да

Comment: а вы учитываете, что у cmd свой php.ini?

Comment: Подробности о том под чем используется php (OS, mod_php или php-fpm)

Comment: @chernomyrdin  Linux, mod_php5

Comment: Если диcnрибутив linux-а `ubuntu`/`debian` то проверьте что у вас в `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` и содержимое директории `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d` про другие дистрибутивы на память - не скажу

Answer (score 0):

В Windows, функция exec() стартует cmd.exe для запуска команды. Если вы хотите запустить внешнюю программу без запуска cmd.exe, то используйте функцию proc_open() с установленной опцией bypass_shell. [Источник](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php)

Comment: сервер не на винде

Comment: А на чем тогда? Можно подробнее?

Comment: Linux vision1.beget.ru 4.6.5-0-beget-acl #1, mod_php5